# From 5 Cols to 4 Cols in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a layout of 10 items with Bootstrap.

- 5 cols In wide (large desktop) screens
- 4 cols when screen gets smaller (laptop/tablet for example)

For example:

Large Screen:

X X X X X

X X X X X

Smaller Screen:

X X X X

X X X X

X X

When I do something like this:

```
<div class='row'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
 <div calss='col'>
</div>
```

On 4 cols per row, it looks like this:

X X X X

X

X X X X

X

How can I avoid those line drops? and still achieve a 5 columns layout (not 6) on wide screens?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're splitting the columns by row, that's why you get the 5th column showing on it's own. The only way you can get what you want is probably to not use Bootstrap columns and set the width's manually - remember that Bootstrap isn't going to do everything for you all the time. So 20% wide would be 5 columns and 25% equates to 4 columns. For example, this is a quick and dirty example.

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col {
    width: 25%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='col'>1</div>
 <div class='col'>2</div>
 <div class='col'>3</div>
 <div class='col'>4</div>
 <div class='col'>5</div>
 <div class='col'>6</div>
 <div class='col'>7</div>
 <div class='col'>8</div>
 <div class='col'>9</div>
 <div class='col'>10</div>
</div>
```